# what's the difference of pushViewController and addSubview

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I create a ViewController named "YLJTestViewController" by interface builder ,code is like:

```
-(IBAction)DoneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    YLJTestViewController *testViewController = [[YLJTestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YLJTestViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
    //[self.view addSubview:testViewController.view];
}
```

but when I use `[self.view addSubview:textViewController.view];`it crashed,but use `[self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];`it works well,so what's the difference?I thought they are the same...

Answer (score 3):

`pushViewController` is like adding a piece of paper onto a stack of paper, while `addSubView` is like gluing a piece of paper onto another paper.

There is no explicit relationships between the previous view and the new view of the view controller which is pushed (like the pieces of paper are still separated in the stack). While the parent view will keep a strong reference to its subviews (like glue).

Answer (score 2):

`-addSubview:` is a method of UIView. It inserts a view into another view. Like adding a button on a page.

`-pushViewController:` is a method of UINavigationController. It pushes a view controller onto a navigation stack. Like sliding from a table view to a details view.

In short, `-addSubview:` composes a view. `-pushViewController:` is a transition between views.

Answer (score 1):

As sptrakesh states in [this Apple Support forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3142391?start=0&tstart=0):

> addSubview is a lower level feature, which you use to add additional
>   views to your parent/main view.  pushViewController replaces the
>   current main view in your window with the view associated with the new
>   view controller.  You use presentModalViewController when you want to
>   display a view modally (blocks previous view) on top of your current
>   view.  If you use full screen for your modal view controller, there is
>   not too much difference between pushViewController and this in terms
>   how the UI behaves.  When you use pushViewController you can "pop" to
>   any view controller in the array of view controllers that have been
>   pushed, which is not as easy to do with nested modal views.

Comment: If you copy language from other source, you must properly cite them. I've done that here, but please do this in the future or this will be considered plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is not the use of `addSubview:` vs. `pushViewController:animated:`, but simply a typo when you use `addSubview:`.

```
[self.view addSubview:textViewController.view]; // misspelled
```

Should be (replacing x with s)

```
[self.view addSubview:testViewController.view]; // correct
```

As for the difference between `addSubview:` vs. `pushViewController:animated:`, others have already made good answers. Basically you should use `pushViewController:animated:` when you replace your entires screen's content, and `addSubview:` when you add non-full screen UI elements to an existing view.

When we are talking about the view of a `UIViewController`, `pushViewController:animated:` should be your preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently ran into similar problems with `addSubview` and `pushViewController`. Everyone here has made great comments, but I would add one things:

Usually `addSubview` is not used by itself. You usually are using it with `presentModalViewController`, or in the case of controller containment, `addChildViewController`.

So in summary:

1. If you are using navigation controllers, you use p`ushViewController`**/**`popViewController` to navigate through your app.
2. If you are manually switching views, use `presentModalViewController`.
3. If you are doing controller containment, use `addChildViewController`.
4. If you are using story boards, use Segues.