# Differences between addSubview vs presenting modal ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

For iOS development, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using `addSubview` versus presenting a view controller modally (using `present(viewController)`?

It seems to me like you can get essentially all of the advantages of presenting a view controller modally by adding a child subView (if you need controller logic, you can just add a child view controller) and you can handle presentation and dismissal animations manually. It seems easier to just `addSubview` and deal with presentation logic yourself as opposed to dealing with presentation logic through the creation of a UIPresentationController, etc.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something, but I don't know enough about views and view controllers to know what. Please help!

Comment: Why would you want to "handle presentation and dismissal animations manually" when iOS does it for you?

Comment: For difficult animations and presentations -for instance, non full screen modal presentations - it seems easier to me to just add a subview that covers the target part of the screen as opposed to dealing with that code in UIPresentationController.

Comment: Great! You've just answered your own question.

Comment: presenting a modal VC is ez. You just make a popup on a separate VC and present it modally. Just present dismiss. You can set Gesture recognizers on the main view on the VC to dismiss the VC.

Comment: For one-off uses, I'm okay doing it manually. The benefit of moving your custom animations into the built-in presentation framework is reusability and separation of duties. If you plan to use this kind of animation in more than one place, doing it manually is not the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before: [what's the difference of pushViewController and addSubview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11083551/whats-the-difference-of-pushviewcontroller-and-addsubview)

> (Presenting) is like adding a piece of paper onto a stack of paper, while addSubView is like gluing a piece of paper onto another paper. There is no explicit relationships between the previous view and the new view of the view controller which is pushed (like the pieces of paper are still separated in the stack). While the parent view will keep a strong reference to its subviews (like glue).

I find that I use both. I will include some code from a project I was messing around with yesterday that might help demonstrate a bit.

I like to create subviews when I am creating a PopUp and do not want to modify the navigation stack. You will notice that I modify the frame to be only part of the screen.

Here is adding subview:

```
    let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "SpaceSettings", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsColorPopUpViewController") as! SettingsColorPopUpViewController
    self.addChild(popOverVC)
    let lSs = UIScreen.main.bounds
    popOverVC.view.frame = CGRect(x: lSs.width/2-200, y: lSs.height/2-250, width: 400, height: 500)
    popOverVC.view.tag = tag
    self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
    popOverVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```

I like to present when I am fully changing the view controller and would like to either flush data or simply make it clear to the user they are in a different place with the app than where they were before. This notably changes the navigation stack which is useful depending on how your app works.
Here is a snippet where I present:

```
    let viewController:UIViewController = (UIStoryboard(name: "SpaceSettings", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingUpTwoViewController") as? SettingUpTwoViewController)!
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

You should be open to both, since neither is superior and it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I do not agree, I think modals are great for popups, you just make a popup on a VC present it and you can add a gesture on the main view of the modal to dismiss the controller and that's it. Very easy to use and you can reuse it.

Comment: Yeah they can be great popups too :) I don't think I said anywhere that they couldn't be :) Thats why I tried to be clear in expressing that I am only giving my opinion and what I do. It really does depend on what you are trying to do and what you prefer. It is true though that one is like gluing and the other is like placing on top.